# fatal: remote error: Could not find Repository octocat/myapp

Tags: git, github

I am using Git for the first time and just forked one open source project following [GitHub's instructions](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/).
I am able to clone my fork on local computer but I get an error when running these commands:

```
$git remote add upstream git://github.com/octocat/myappname.git
$ git fetch upstream
```

`git fetch` gives me this error:

```
fatal: remote error: Could not find Repository octocat/myappname
```

How can I resolve this error and fetch the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you did a straight copy/paste from the docs, but just to be sure, your environment might not be set up correctly. If the repo you're forking is called *testproject* , your username is *me* and their username is *they* :

You should have forked and then cloned your repo. Your repo's address is ssh://git@github.com/me/testproject  **notice the ssh protocol**

Then, you should have added *they's* repo as an upstream repo (that's the git remote add upstream). Github provides a link you can copy there, but you should use the git protocol if possible (see VonC's note about git, http and firewall). The command to add the upsteam repo is `git remote add upstream git://github.com/they/testproject` Note that upstream is arbitrary. You can name it upstream or anything else you want. Also, make sure to get the /they and /testproject right as that will cause errors if the repo doesn't exist in that user's account

Comment: :Thank you.your 'me' and 'they' things really helped:-)

Answer (score 1):

You should put your username instead of octocat. The account octocat just has the repositories Spoon-Knife and Hello-World and is an testaccount from the company Github.

Or did you fork the Spoon-Knife repository from octocat?

Comment: :Instead of octocat, I used maintainers username and it worked. Thank you for your time to provide answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using http address (or https address if you need to also push)

```
git remote add upstream http://github.com/octocat/myappname
```

Comment: (git port might be blocked by your company proxy or your local firewall)