# why i failed to push to git repo?

Tags: git, version-control, google-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fatal: remote error: Could not find Repository octocat/myapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611670/fatal-remote-error-could-not-find-repository-octocat-myapp)

```
https://code.google.com/p/prjname/ is a empty repo right now
```

**i can clone it, but cannot push local repo to it, why?**

```
[mirror@home php]$ git clone https://code.google.com/p/prjname/
Cloning into 'prjname'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
[mirror@home php]$ rm prjname/ -rf
```

**git init**

**Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/mirror/tmp/php/.git/**

```
[mirror@home php]$ git remote -v
[mirror@home php]$ git remote add origin https://code.google.com/p/prjname/
[mirror@home php]$ git push origin
fatal: remote error: Repository not found
[mirror@home php]$ git push -u origin
fatal: remote error: Repository not found
[mirror@home php]$ https://code.google.com/p/prjname/

[mirror@home php]$ ls
conf.inc.php  demo  docs  lang  lib  logs  prjname  sdk.class.php  services  util
```

**failed to push, but this repo exists, though it is empty...**

```
[mirror@home php]$ git push origin
fatal: remote error: Repository not found
```

Comment: Have you seen it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202015/code-google-com-git-fatal-remote-error-repository-not-found

Comment: @kan this problem is a bit similar with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202015/code-google-com-git-fatal-remote-error-repository-not-found, but mine is with more details, and that question is still unsolved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
cd prjname
git push origin
```

Comment: current dir is already local repo dir